# Apostrophe Offset in Equation Environment

Tags: math-mode, positioning

There is a noticeable offset when an apostrophe is used in the TeX math mode (`$`...`$`) versus `equation` environment.  Here's a MWE showing this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\centering
$k'$

\[
    k'
\]

\end{document}
```

The apostrophe (or prime symbol, if you prefer) is noticeably higher in the `equation` environment than in math mode, which is not what I would expect.  What causes this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package is not really necessary here...

Comment: I was under the mistaken belief that `amsmath` provided the `equation` environment, so I thought it was necessary.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It does provide `equation*`, which is similar to `\[`...`\]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equation` environment sets its contents in `\displaystyle` by default, while `$`...`$` is set using `\textstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\centering
$k' \quad \displaystyle k'$

\[k' \quad {\textstyle k'}\]

\end{document}
```

Put the relevant elements inside a group and issue `\textstyle` to achieve the same setting. Other options are also possible, but this is the root cause of the change.

Comment: In the end, I prefer how `equation` does it, so I did the reverse of your suggestion:  adding `\displaystule` to the math mode expression to stay consistent.  I think either approach is valid as long as I stay consistent.